# Passing variable javascript to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to pass a single variable from javascript to PHP using jQuery AJAX.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ok').on('click', function(e){

        var value = 5;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'tabulka.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {x : value},
            success: function(){
                alert(value);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
    $value = $_POST['x'];
    echo $value;
}
```

I get the alert from ajax with the expected value but in PHP I get this error: `Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\tabulka.php on line 71`
When I uncomment the `dataType: 'json'` I don't even get the alert from AJAX.

Comment: Alert print right value.

Comment: The error is coming from some other part of your PHP code that you haven't shared with us, where `['value']` is being used as an array index.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
data: ({value : value}),
```

Try using this,

```
 data: "value="+value,
```

And you are not at all passing "OK" but you are receiving it. If you want to pass OK also as a parameter try this.

```
data: "value="+value+"&OK=Somevalue",
```

That should work.

Comment: @JanMaděra : Check my updated answer. You might have tried `data: "value="+value,` but then you might not have got the error but a blank response. But when you tried this `data: ({value : value}),` you got an error. Am I right ?

Comment: I don't want to pass OK just the value. I got error in both cases.

Comment: If you don't want to pass OK just remove this `&& isset($_POST['OK'])`

Comment: That just check if i click OK button. That have nothing to do with the ajax I think. I make some edit to code. But that didn't help.

Comment: Yeah, that has nothing to do with the AJAX but think, you are using it in the `if` condition with `AND`. If you don't pass any values for "OK" it will not go inside the `if`. Do you have any `.htaccess` file used ?

Comment: It goes to if conditon because the error gives me undefined index. So the if condition is okey I think. No i don't have any .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript

```
data: {'value' : value}
```

**notice the single quote and no parenthesis**

Your PHP:

```
If(isset($_POST['value'])){
   $val = $_POST['value'];
}
```

Your JavaScript was formatted incorrectly.  `data` is an object, or an associative array in other words.

Your PHP code has unnecessary string comparison.  Whenever a post is made to a PHP script,  you will access them using $_POST array.

For instance, if you posted this via AJAX

```
data:{ 'name' : 'jake', 'age' : 1024}
```

You would access them in PHP by

```
  $name = $_POST['name']
    $age = $_POST['age']
```

Also, it is wise to use PHP `isset` to verify that a post variable exists before trying to access them.  That way you will not have an exception if expected post data is not.

Comment: Didn't change anything for me. The problem must by somewhere else. Ajax pass the data right but the SERVER don't recognize the 'x' index.

Answer (score 0):

check following line

```
var value = $(this).find('td:first').html();
```

set some hard coded value for 'value' variable like below

```
var value='some value';
```

if above works then check the value you assigned using `$(this).find('td:first').html()`