# How to use ajax in order to pass variables values to a php script?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to use ajax and pass varuables from js to php in order to insert them in a mysql table. 
the code below is successful in calling the php script but not passing the data

i would like to pass "num"  from the following js function to "insertRow.php" - the function does activate "insertRow.php" but will not pass the data

```
function InsertToTable(num){
    var data=num;
    $.ajax({
        url: "insertRow.php",
        data: data,
        type: "POST"
        });
```

once the data is passed i would like to insert it in to a mysql table, the following will work if i don't use "$num" but just put a value instead

```
<?php
$num = $_Post['data'];
//print_r($_Post("data"));

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "Schedule";   

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql ="INSERT INTO `temp1` (`column1`) VALUES ('$num')";

$conn->query($sql);     
?>
```

Comment: `$_POST` is case sensitive.

Comment: Please read about [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variable javascript to PHP using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106810/passing-variable-javascript-to-php-using-ajax)

Comment: I bet this has been asked and answered tons of time. Give a try to do more searches. (Not my downvote)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this...

```
data: {data : num},
```

OR, since you set `data = num;` you could do this:

```
data: {data: data},
```

Where the first `data` is the identifier and the second is the value.

The will give you access to data in the POST (which is case sensitive) variable:

```
$_POST['data'] // should be equal to num
```

Comment: Althought this is legit, `data: {data: data}` will be very confusing.

Comment: Agreed @Cid, because especially in this case `num` is already set and does not need to be transfigured into another variable.

Comment: What about `var data = { data:num };` so you can type `data: { data: data.data }` ?

Comment: @Cid LOL ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ It works on my computer <- my pre-made comment for some questions

Comment: Of course it does @Cid, it is legitimate, although confusing, code.

Comment: It reminds me an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52621998/8398549) I posted about SQL

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a typo,

Insead of

```
$num = $_Post['data'];
```

Try

```
$num = $_POST['data'];
```

Also, it's good practice to send AJAX a return, so in the end you can use

```
echo json_encode(true);
```

Or set it to false in case of an error, with this you can see if the query worked or not in the success clause of AJAX.

Here's an example of a more complex AJAX call.

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'scripts/AjaxHandler/Controller.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    action: 'doThis',
                    var1: var1,
                    var2: var2
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data == true) {
                        alert('success');
                    }else{
                        alert('failure');
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```